# System.String[] argv conversion to string

Tags: c#, string

Good Morning,
I have a problem with my WPF application, I need to use this method:

```
public static void  LaunchTraining(System.String[] argv)
    {
        svm_train t = new svm_train();
        t.run(argv);
    }
```

The problem is that I do not have a stream from the Console (the input is a filename), but I need to declare the name of the file for this method, example:

```
string filename = "training.txt";
```

How can I convert my string into System.String[] argv?

Comment: `t.run(new []{ filename });`? (or `LaunchTraining(new []{ filename });`)

Comment: Do you mean simply passing the filename to the LaunchTraining function? You can create an array with one item - new[] {filename};

Comment: use `LaunchTraining(new []{filename});`

Answer (score 1):

There is no feasible way to do what you want.

The best solution would be to create an overload:

```
public static void  LaunchTraining(String argv) {
    // Handle String instead of String[]
}
```

Alternatively you could make an array:

```
LaunchTraining(new[]{"training.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need the first item of the argv:

```
if(argv.Any()) t.run(argv[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this static method like below

```
LaunchTraining(new []{filename});
```